# Parse query where key contains A or B - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pfquery

I am trying to run a parse query where a certain field contains either todays date or tomorrows date. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var date = Date() // first date
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date2 = (calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: date, options: [])!
    let dateFormatter:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let todaysString:String = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    let tomorrowString:String = dateFormatter.string(from: date2)

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Events")
    query.whereKey("dateString", contains: todaysString || tomorrowString)
```

But this will not run because it cannot convert the value. Does anyone know how I am suppose to write this line to show that dateString needs to contain either todaysString or tomorrowString? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to create two seperate query, Q1for todaysString and Q2 for  tomorrowString. Now add both queries in an Array. And use PFQuer method "orQueryWithSubqueries" to merge them in 3rd query Q3 and then execute the 3rd query Q3.
I have used this in objective c and worked for me, i can post objective c code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate queries, and join them with `PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries(todayQuery, tomorrowQuery)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two separate query, Q1for todaysString and Q2 for tomorrowString. Now add both queries in an Array. And use PFQuery's function "orQueryWithSubqueries" to merge them in 3rd query Q3 and then execute the 3rd query Q3. I have used this in objective c and worked for me, I can post objective c code if you want